# Issue with address field in formula

Tags: formula-field, address

I have to use an address field in a formula field but the formula returns the following error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'IF()'. Expected Location, received Text

The formula is as follows:

```
IF(MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_CodigoAlmacen__c = '8058', MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c,
    IF(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'MSM_Distribuidor',
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.BillingStreet), "" & BR() , MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.BillingStreet & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.BillingCity), "" & BR(), MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.BillingCity & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.BillingPostalCode), "" & BR(), MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.BillingPostalCode & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.BillingCountry), "" & BR(), MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.BillingCountry & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(Account.Phone), "" & BR(), Account.Phone & BR()), 
    IF(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'MSM_DireccionEntrega',
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.ShippingStreet), "" & BR(), MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.ShippingStreet & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.ShippingCity), "" & BR(), MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.ShippingCity & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.ShippingPostalCode), "" & BR(), MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.ShippingPostalCode & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.ShippingCountry), "" & BR(), MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.ShippingCountry & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.Phone), "" & BR(), MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r.Phone & BR()), 
    "")
    )
)
```

MSM_CodigoAlmacen__c is a string and MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c is the Address field.

Is there any way to solve the error?

**Edit**: Added actual formula

Comment: The `CustomFieldA__c = 'X',` bit looks like it'd be the issue, but it's hard to say what the fix would be with it being obfuscated/generic-ified. Seeing the actual field name and value you're testing against would be helpful (also, is `CustomFieldA__c` a field of type Location? or is it a relationship field to an SObject named "Location"?). Please [edit] your question to add that clarification.

Comment: Best guess right now is that you need to be using [the `GEOLOCATION()` function](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_geolocation.htm&type=5) in concert with `DISTANCE()`

Comment: @derekF I have added the formula, how it makes you see the idea more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `then` and `else` parameters of an `IF()` must be the same datatype.

From some brief experimenting, it looks like Salesforce is treating Address fields (a type of compound field) as a `Location`, and there's no function to convert that into a textual representation. The only functions that can work with a Location are `DISTANCE()` and `GEOLOCATION()` (which itself can only be used in `DISTANCE()`). [Salesforce does say that `DISTANCE()` doesn't work with custom Address fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_caf_requirements.htm&type=5).

What you need to do here is access the individual parts of your `MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c` Address field just like you are with the ShippingAddress/BillingAddress from `MSM_ClienteEnvioPdV__r`. Accessing those for a custom address field is a little different. The format is `<field api name> + __ + <address component> + __s`

i.e. `MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c__Street__s`

So your formula should look like

```
IF(
    MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_CodigoAlmacen__c = '8058',
    IF(ISBLANK(MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c__Street__s), "" & BR() , MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c__Street__s & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c__City__s), "" & BR(), MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c__City__s & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c__PostalCode__s), "" & BR(), MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c__PostalCode__s & BR()) &
        IF(ISBLANK(MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c__Country__s), "" & BR(), MSM_AlmacenCarga__r.MSM_DireccionAlmacen__c__CountryCode__s
    /* and then the rest of your formula is unchanged */
)
```

+edit: the "address" component for Country is actually `CountryCode`, as noted by OP in the comments. Answer has been updated to address that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. It worked! The only drawback is that I can't use Country__s, you can't select it, It has to be CountryCode__s. I have marked your answer as solution.